# ASP.Net MVC how does back-end know if user signed in

Tags: c#

I created a ASP.Net C# MVC app with "Individual User Account" for Authentication + localDB. I started the app in visual studio with IIS express on localhost, signed up an user and logged in with that user.

I am trying to understand how back-end know a user has logged in in the following scenario:

1. start the iis express & app in visual studio
2. log in
3. stop the iis express & app in visual studio
4. start again the iis express & app in visual studio
5. user still logged in (WHY???)

I checked the user tables in db, and could not find any fields indicate a logged in user. I am thinking stop & restart iis express should clear everything in the back-end as well.

So how does the back-end know there was an user logged in in the step 5 above??

I found the following cookie in the http request

Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1546797954.1551225891; __RequestVerificationToken=PSFeb9iP4aZr3wxxb8nJNKtki_1XPTzGO1Hzaf0W3iDsSCnV_qCfMsC9TY980X51c2rANZA-zureu6UHKEssAHza58AdmQUdZVL98VGYlRc1; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=VUPznoprBRK2z13u03ArrC9HLHeGGUyTSvu9rYpSnZju_Rz4X2V5n9faw0EhnmuFjVN1AIva7HZSAhUBeSZ5jQHSej6XaAExy0hkwF_9vC190LfWBPP-oH3Zp0jj0ZmZ7L3sLlLqux4HV5CZSA-jqhDF4IXAFKyisFFV136PlxrJTmb9OXRrmo9rigCiIy0z_oixDlg1eHVI3T6ptVgn1Qhohtr1mTqoBJsF7gi7CHymSBlyFJ5MgYxfPcWNhJnj3H-WWK1ijkfzxsm0R13m2_6IbIiK1y5uzQBkklb8oMuz0mD27GlwMzteQBP3VLOXn77BreOPefJ8_2AekYjFGjgBIGGpngxLVzDneT4rC-BDiVKdWO_FRuail4ivVAN2ZJtdjK0uEPqnln5rmOlT0MLAhYzHMkk-HTvtW-Xo-Kexinlh58uxz0E7bncY5I6troc19E0fBLMnfXThtaL7ur6CN4pqUyq4yALJCTHszG3RPLQoJja0u1g34i-mKunZ

Comment: it is very basic concept in web development.it is browser cookie behind the things.when you sign-in membership system adds a cookie to request by means of which membership system tracks the user by sending the same cookie with subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks, I do found this in the cookie (I updated the question with the cookie information). Seems to be encrypted(?). Are there any documents explain what information is included in this cookie, and how does the information processed in the back-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web development there is very basic concept called cookie.The cookie is responsible too store user information in browser. When you sign-in in membership system ,it adds a special header called `Set-Cookie` to response which afterward get's stored in browser cache.The information send through header contains information about loged in user's identity. With subsequent requests browser send the same cookie to the server and the membership system parses that info to identify the user which makes request and if the information is valid you are logged in and system identifies you.

EDIT :
The detail of operations taking place is not unique and depends on which library you use for authentication but if you use asp.net default authentication system then you can go and see how things get done in the source code.For  `ASP.NET CORE` check https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity and for `ASP.NET MVC` check : https://github.com/aspnet/Identity

Comment: Thanks, i found that piece of cookie. See my question above. It seems to be encrypted. Do you know what infomation included In the cookie and how is it decrypted by  backend?

Answer (score 0):

Following is how authentication works in ASP.NET MVC

1. Enter Username and password in login form and click on "Login" button
2. On click of Login button Server side code checks whether entered Username and Password exists in database
3. If entered Username and Password exists in database then server side code creates cookie and stores them in the browser(not in the database)
4. On every page request IIS checks whether authentication cookie exists or not.
5. If cookie exists then user is logged In and if cookie doesn't exist the user is not logged in

Since authentication cookie is stored in browser and not in IIS. Stopping and Starting IIS has no effect on User log in status.

**To answer your specific question: So how does the back-end know there was an user logged in in the step 5 above??
Ans:** On ever page request from IIS. Along with other information, authentication cookie  stored in browser is sent to back-end/IIS. back-end/IIS then checks whether or not authentication cookie is valid. If cookie is valid back-end/IIS knows user is logged in. If cookie is invalid back-end/IIS knows user is not logged in.

To understand this process further. I would recommend reading about cookies first and then read about authentication in ASP.NET.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I should dig into how the authentication feature encrypt & decrypt cookie.